# Issue with managing jenkins

Tags: jenkins, ubuntu-14.04

I have installed jenkins on my ubunut 14.10 as mentioned on this page [install jenkins on ubunutu](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Installing+Jenkins+on+Ubuntu), after installation I started it by accessing port 8080.

I can not see any link to create new job or manage jenkins. I am not sure if there any change or do I have to do any other kind of setting, please help. This is my screen now.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am quite sure this is due to the fact, that the user you used for login has not the permission to create new jobs. You have to login as admin and create a user with the correct permissions or add them to your existing user. Also you may need to install plugins if you want to use maven jobs for example. A standard security setup is explained [here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Standard+Security+Setup)